# Error with indenxing with [] in c#

Tags: c#

```
     int average(int [] a, int k)
    {
        int average, s, i, n;

        s = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
        {
            a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(lblSortiranNiz.Items[i]);
            s = s + a[i];
        }
        average = s / k;
        return average;
    }
```

Thank you for help but now i dont know how to put it into my main program

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        int i, j, n, pom, average1;
        n = lblBrojevi.Items.Count;
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(lblBrojevi.Items[i]);
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                if (a[i] > a[j])
                {
                    pom = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = pom;
                }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            lblSortiranNiz.Items.Add(a[i]);
        }
        average1 = prosek(a[i], 3);
        tbaverage.Text = Convert.ToString(average1);
    }
```

i tried like this with number 3 as k, but it doesnt work, it give me some wrong small number. please help me if you can.

Comment: the parameter named "a" is not an array and you are using the index ([]) operator with it.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, you can't index an int. Perhaps you should be acceptiong an array instead?

Comment: how to make an array could you help me, i dont know that

Comment: You should not edit your question to add the fix to your code.  That just makes reading this question and the answers confusing for anyone that looks at this post latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter named "a" is not an array and you are using the index ([]) operator with it. Besides, considering k as number of elements you are missing the last element when you are computing the average:

```
int average(int[] a, int k)
{
    int average, s, i, n;

    s = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(lblSortiranNiz.Items[i]);
        s = s + a[i];
    }
    average = s / k;
    return average;
}
```

Actually you do not need the k argument since an array has a [Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

It seems to be a homework, but just to know, you can use the [Average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extension method in LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `int` as array of `int`. You should fix it by replacing the first line with the following:

```
 int average(int[] a, int k)
```

Answer (score 1):

the data type of the method you used is int ,
you just need to use array data type.

just like that.

`int average(int []a, int k)`

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using LINQ? Here is a sample:

```
var avarage = lblSortiranNiz.Items.Select(i=>Convert.ToInt32(i))
                                  .Take(k)
                                  .Sum() / k;
```